# mingw finds the symbols but not the library

Tags: linker, mingw, symbols

In msys2, I am trying to compile and if I don't add -lfreetype-6 I get the (obvious) error messages about a bunch of missing symbols, for example:

```
... undefined reference to `FT_Init_FreeType'
... undefined reference to `FT_New_Face'
... undefined reference to `FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes'
```

and so on. When I add -lfreetype-6 to my linking command, the "undefined reference to" stuff is gone and instead I get,

```
../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lfreetype-6: No such file or directory
```

How is it possible for gcc to resolve the symbols but later complain that it doesn't find the library where it found the symbols. This does not make sense. And here's the installed library,

```
$ pacman -Ss freetype
mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-freetype 2.12.1-1
    TrueType font rendering library (mingw-w64)
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-freetype 2.12.1-1 [installed]
    TrueType font rendering library (mingw-w64)
ucrt64/mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-freetype 2.12.1-1
    TrueType font rendering library (mingw-w64)
clang32/mingw-w64-clang-i686-freetype 2.12.1-1
    TrueType font rendering library (mingw-w64)
clang64/mingw-w64-clang-x86_64-freetype 2.12.1-1
    TrueType font rendering library (mingw-w64)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the compile step is able to find everything it needs in the header files while the linker step is trying to resolve each symbol to actual code but fails to find these symbols.

If you don't link with the right libraries you will get `undefined reference`.

For `-lfreetype-6` to work you must make sure you have the file `libfreetype-6.a` (static) or `libfreetype-6.dll.a` (shared) on your system. To make the linker find this file add the folder's path to your linker command with the `-L` flag.